# Interrogation droid syringe "British Made"

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, droids, a-new-hope, retcon

In *Episode IV:  A New Hope*, an interrogation droid is used to torture Leia.

[image]
*Screencap from the movie*

This droid is equipped with a syringe.

[image]
*Photo of the actual prop in a museum*

This syringe is clearly labeled "BRITISH MADE".

[image]
*Photo of the actual prop in a museum*

Obviously, Britain isn't in the Galaxy Far, Far Away, so this poses a problem for sticklers for continuity like... um... almost everyone on this site.  Knowing the penchant Lucas and other *Star Wars* writers have for questionable retcons, I have to ask:

### Was the appearance of "BRITISH MADE" in a *Star Wars* movie ever retconned or mentioned elsewhere, at any level of canonicity?

---

*Note:  I realize the label is all but impossible to see in the film, but I have heard people claim that they saw it there.  Difficult for sure, but perhaps it is **possible**.*

Comment: Ehm, is the photo with the readable "EVERETT" actually a screencap from the film? Was its resolution that high?

Comment: @MrLister - Photos of the actual prop in a museum.  But I've seen people claiming that they saw it in the film.

Comment: Incidentally, the poor little torture droid appears to have suffered some rough handling over the years.  Chipped paint, dents, scratches, etc.

Comment: Unless you can post an actual screencap from the film in which the label is legible, then there's no question to answer. A prop when seen off-screen is not canonical.

Comment: @MikeScott  - Non sequitur.  Whether or not the label is canon, it could have been mentioned somewhere.

Comment: You can say it's still a valid question to ask whether the label was "mentioned elsewhere, at any level of canonicity", but if the premise of an "appearance of BRITISH MADE in a Star Wars movie" is false, the question should be modified. And of course, if it never appeared, it'd never need to be "retconned".

Comment: @hypnosifl - If the label is mentioned, it needs a retcon to explain what "British" means

Comment: Maybe this is pedantic, but a retcon is when one source presents something, and then a later source tries to explain it away. If the label didn't actually appear in the movie and there was some other source that first presented it as existing in-universe later (I highly doubt any Lucasfilm-approved source ever did, but I'm speaking hypothetically), then if that *same* source also offered an in-universe explanation of what "British Made" meant, it wouldn't really be a "retcon".

Comment: I don't see the problem. In my opinion a faraway galaxy is much more likely to have a place called Britain than to have beings as close to human as we see in the movie. A "British made" label would be the least of many implausibilities, such as galactic empires/republics, hyperspace travel, or the "force".

Comment: Too much semantics for me at 4 am.  Off to bed.

Comment: @MikeScott - Besides, you're just wrong - if the label isn't seen onscreen and not mentioned elsewhere, that means the answer is "No". That is pretty much the opposite of not having a question to ask.  (Sorry, I saw that I had posted this with "your" instead of "you're" [stupid autocorrect], and I had to fix it)

Comment: Follow up question: Who forgot to remove the label and were they fired or simply Force Choke'd to death?

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether the droid was called ["Krollspell"](https://tintin.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Krollspell)

Answer (score 25):

Firstly, you'll note that the syringe in the movie is the other way up (it's quite likely so that the words "British made" *aren't* visible), and whatever it said on *this* side isn't necessarily the same as on the other side!

Getting past that, it would be *highly* unlikely that anyone ever could make out the words from just the movie.  Below is a screen grab from Harmy's 1080p Despecialized Edition: the syringe from the movie, and while you can see... something, it's not legible what the words are.

[image]

So the only way that anyone would know *for sure* what it said would have been at the museum exhibit, which is not even close to canon.  *If* someone had seen the exhibit, there's a *chance* that they'd be able to make out the words that they knew were there while watching the movie.  However, if you had to run blind on what it said on there, I suspect that there would be very, very few - if any - who could tell you what is written there without out-of-universe knowledge.