# Are there branded products designed for mass consumption in the “Star Wars” universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

So we live in a modern world where mass marketed products surround us every day. But what about mass marketed products within the universe of “A galaxy far, far away?”

So that’s the question:

#### In the *Star Wars* universe are there such things as popular soft-drink beverages, fashion brands and other sundry/basic consumer items?

It seems to me — just from watching the films — that the only explicitly branded products mentioned are vehicles, military weapons and droids. But things — such as Chewbacca’s bowcaster — are hand made. And when we see people eat in the films — such as on Tatooine — we see people seemingly making food products from scratch. But is there a *Star Wars* version of fast food, fashion brands and the like?

So is there any kind of brand name products characters in the *Star Wars* universe would consume in some way? Is this touched on in the extended universe or “legends” canon?

---

<sup>Please note — and to clarify what I state above — I am ***not* looking for more examples of vehicles, military weapons and droids…** I am well aware those are mass marketed commodities in the *Star Wars* universe. What I ***am* looking for are examples of basic/everyday consumer items.**</sup>

Comment: Well, there's the Yoda Halloween costume found in ET...(http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/are-e-t-and-star-wars-in-the-same-universe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are some in Legends. For example:

[Aquaware](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aquawear):

> Aquawear was a brand of swimwear for females that was manufactured by AthleticGal.

[Hypergym](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HyperGym):

> HyperGym was the brand name of a line of personal exercise equipment.

[Star Rush](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Rush):

> Star Rush was a brand linked to interstellar travel and luggage transportation. It had stickers on certain luggage cases at the Tomorrowland Starport.

[Utozz](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Utozz):

> Utozz was a brand of Utoz (alcoholic beverage) manufactured by the Utozz Prime Brewery Corporation.

There was also possibly at least one in Canon in the form of [Westhills butter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Westhills_butter).

You can see a bunch Legends and Canon brands [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=brand&fulltext=Search&page=1&ns0=1&ns14=1&ns112=1). Just be warned that some pages use "Brand" as a name or location.

Answer (score 7):

I'm gonna be that guy: The Star Wars Holiday Special.

There is, of course, the groomer:

[image]

*Evidently, you haven't read the 
               instructions, the warranty, and the 
               guarantee.
               ... besides shaving and hair trimming. 
               It's guaranteed to lift stains off 
               clothing, faces, and hands. Cleans teeth, 
               fingers, and toenails. Washes eyes, 
               pierces ears, calculates, modulates, and
               syncopates like rhythms and can repeat 
               the entire Imperial Code, all 17 volumes, 
               in half the time of the old XP-21. Just 
               the thing to keep you squeaky clean.*

Syndicated television, Chef Gormaanda and Life on Tatooine

[image]

[image]

Cartoons, complete with logos and tie-ins!

[image]

And, of course, the Mini Transmitter, although that might not qualify as an everyday consumer item.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm sticking to canon examples.

### [TaggeCo Dewormer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TaggeCo#cite_note-Survival-1)

> Galacti-Stok was a subsidiary of TaggeCo. One product it distributed
>   was Happy-Bore Medicated Dewormer, a dewormer designed to control and
>   rid happabores of parasites.

Comment: Properly I should be referencing Rey's Survival Guide, but since I can't find it....

Answer (score 1):

**Hey, that's my dinner!** (fish-stick-looking-thing in ESB)

Manufacturer: unknown.

Constituents: unknown.

Smell: presumed to be unappetizing.

Taste: confirmed to be unappetizing.

Yoda's vote: *"blah."*

---

Alas, this might just be considered a military ration as there is no branding on the case it came out of, but this is as close to a G-Canon Star Wars version of fast food as you'll get. I think its reasonable to assume that Luke did not prepare that kit and that many others just like it were made.

I doubt the rebels are into trademarking their gear, quite the opposite actually. If you get caught with an *Imperial Ration Kit #27*, you're charged with thievery. Caught with a *Rebel Fish Stick Dinner* (now with more sauce!), you'll be branded as a traitor and taken away.

---

Out-of-universe, NO.

Thankfully, Star Wars was not written by Tolkien. Also, in the previous millennium, brand recognition was not as prevalent in the minds of your average citizen as it is today, and their use as a plot device is mostly a recent invention.

---

So-far-out-of-universe, it's in ours. Britain to be more precise:

[Interrogation droid syringe “British Made”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115959/interrogation-droid-syringe-british-made)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "Thankfully, Star Wars was not written by Tolkien."?  I can't think of any branded products in his writing, but I'd be glad to post the question.

Comment: My gibe at Tolkien was about how (I think) he thought that to make a good story, you have to invent a bunch of history and give everything profusely long names to bring the story to life. It has nothing to do with branding, it's about how Lucas was able to give his stories depth, without actually including a history lesson. *Behold, the Blender of Insanity! Bequeathed upon Margol, son of Moor, father of the Lords of the West and leader of its peoples, brought to you by the letter A and the number 6. Order now! Not available in stores!*