# Why does Han Solo's blaster have a hammer and what is its purpose?

Tags: star-wars

I am 3d printing Han Solo's blaster pistol (because why not) and realized:

[image]

It definitely looks like it has a hammer mechanism... which, makes no sense to me in the Star Wars universe, where a blaster fires energy from a power pack vs gunpowder.

My understanding is the out of universe explanation is his blaster is an amalgamation of various WWII era weapon components, which would make complete sense for him to have on his pistol (not to mention it fits the look).

From looking, I didn't see other Star Wars energy weapons with such obvious hammer-like mechanisms.

Is there an in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: Out of universe, by the way, the pistol seems simply a Mauser C96 - end of 19th century pistol, - which was used extensively in both WWs, with a blob attached in the  front part of the barrel. Compare yourself https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauser_C96

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection), that 'hammer' is the

> *blast delivery selector*

Basically it's the slider that determines the relative strength of the shot fired. If memory serves, several EU stories mention that Han has had the lower settings removed/disabled in order to make his gun fire efficiently.

[image]

---

Out of universe, the pistol was a [modified C96 Mauser pistol](https://www.guns.com/2012/09/17/gun-review-dl-44-blastech-blaster-pistol/). That part is identified in the owner's manual as simply being the [hammer](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1524/1342/products/MB1085__04.jpg?v=1506652456)

Comment: Perhaps one of the lamest explanations ever but alas, I guess that's what happens when you take a RL pistol and throw it into the Star Wars universe ;)

Comment: And even in the more recent movies, they STILL use real guns and dress 'em up.  https://www.inverse.com/article/47416-netflix-august-2018-here-s-what-s-coming-to-and-leaving-netflix-in-august   I'm actually considering building up the blaster pistol based on a 22lr AR pistol (no recoil spring tube needed so it can be flush at the back end) ...

Comment: @ElysianFields - "[British Made](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115959/interrogation-droid-syringe-british-made)"

Comment: @Valorum at least that one wasn't visible on-screen ;)